# Could not find method firebaseAppDistribution() for arguments

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, firebase-app-distribution

I am trying to implement Firebase App Distribution through Gradle but after I have added this:

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
                releaseNotes="Some release notes"
                testers="email@example.com"
            }
```

and click `Sync Now` for the Gradle to sync with the project, the build fails with:

`Could not find method firebaseAppDistribution() for arguments [...], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.`

I have also added these:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the build might be failing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequence of apply plugin matters

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'
```

firebase.appdistribution plugin should be just below android.application plugin

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:1.1.0'
```

in project/build.gradle file and

Add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'
```

in app/build.gradle file below the android plugin

Comment: The issue was that the

`apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'`

has to be added directly under the

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`;

on the next line. Otherwise it does not work. :D Thanks for your answer. :)